# Data set of Air waybills

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a few hundred completed Air waybills like this [one](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/1151153-mh370-cargo-manifest-and-airway-bill.html). There probably isn't a complete data set for this but does anyone know how I can find a large amount of these?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I am looking for images of the air waybills